# How to construct a hierarchical query in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hierarchy

Hello I have the following data model (simplified):

```
User
   Long getDelegationId();

Expedient
   Long getDelegationId();

Delegation
    Long getId();
    Set<Delegation> getSubDelegations();
    Delegation getParentDelegation();
```

Now I need to create a filter so a User can only see the expedients that belong to his delegation or its subdelegations at 3 lvl depth maximum.

How can I achieve this?

Im trying the following query:

```
from Expedient aliasExpedient where aliasExpedient.delegation.ID in 
( select delegation4.ID from Delegation as delegation1
join fetch delegation1.delegations as delegation2
join fetch delegation2.delegations as delegation3
join fetch delegation3.delegations as delegation4
where delegation1.ID = ?)
```

With the fetch included I get:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: fetch not allowed in subquery from-elements
```

and without it I get no results.

Any hints about how to achieve my goal?

Thanks,
Gonzalo